# Non-compact analogue of Hartog's extension theorem?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose a function $f(z,w)$ is analytic in the open polydisk $\Delta^2$ with $\Delta = \{z \in \mathbb C | |z| < 1 \}$. I am interested in the limit $f(z,w)$ as $w \to 1$. This limit may be singular, for example the function $f(z)/(w-1)$ will blow up for all $z$.

However, if I know that the limit is finite and analytic (in $z$) for certain values of $z$, say in an open subset of $\Delta$, can I say something about the limit for other values of $z \in \Delta$? For example, could the limit be the function $1/z$?